# Failed to push images to harbor with 500 Error

Tags: docker, harbor, kaniko

i'm trying to push images to my harbor registry. I'm sure my account can pull and push. when i use `docker push`  command in terminal it shows `received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error`.

but i test, i can pull image.

I also tried from my ci-cd pipeline using kaniko and it showed more error info:

```
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "myharbor/myrepo/myproject:mytag": POST https://myharbor/myrepo/myproject/blobs/uploads/: UNKNOWN: unknown error; map[DriverName:filesystem Enclosed:map[Err:28 Op:mkdir Path:/storage/docker/registry/v2/repositories/myrepo/myproject/_uploads/511da2fa-5dd0-4b36-af02-0c2034eca0bb]]
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to look at the server logs to see why. The 500 status deliberately contains no information at all.

Comment: the error message from kaniko could be more useful i guess? i guess it means failed to create this tmp directory